Blank Login Page Spring Security 6.2.3 and Spring Boot 3
I am getting a blank page after hitting my custom login page URL i.e. mapped to /login. I am getting a 200 response code but showing an empty page in the browser although I my login page contains the code.
I checked logs and no security is applied to the /login page which is an expected behavior according to my filter chain. Also, the View resolver config is in place for the jsp view.
Below is the trace logs:
[nio-8081-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /login
2024-05-14T12:09:22.640+05:30 TRACE 29983 --- [myapp
] [nio-8081-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking DisableEncodeUrlFilter (1/13)
2024-05-14T12:09:22.641+05:30 TRACE 29983 --- [myapp
] [nio-8081-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter (2/13)
2024-05-14T12:09:22.641+05:30 TRACE 29983 --- [myapp
] [nio-8081-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking SecurityContextPersistenceFilter (3/13)
2024-05-14T12:09:22.641+05:30 TRACE 29983 --- [myapp
] [nio-8081-exec-3] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Did not find SecurityContext in HttpSession b4f82d82-143b-43b7-98f6-27c4b78e141f using the SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT session attribute
2024-05-14T12:09:22.641+05:30 TRACE 29983 --- [myapp
] [nio-8081-exec-3] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Created SecurityContextImpl [Null authentication]
2024-05-14T12:09:22.641+05:30 TRACE 29983 --- [myapp
] [nio-8081-exec-3] .s.s.w.c.SupplierDeferredSecurityContext : Created SecurityContextImpl [Null authentication]
2024-05-14T12:09:22.641+05:30 DEBUG 29983 --- [myapp
] [nio-8081-exec-3] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Set SecurityContextHolder to empty SecurityContext
2024-05-14T12:09:22.641+05:30 TRACE 29983 --- [myapp
] [nio-8081-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking HeaderWriterFilter (4/13)
2024-05-14T12:09:22.641+05:30 TRACE 29983 --- [myapp
] [nio-8081-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking CorsFilter (5/13)
2024-05-14T12:09:22.641+05:30 TRACE 29983 --- [myapp
] [nio-8081-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking LogoutFilter (6/13)
2024-05-14T12:09:22.641+05:30 TRACE 29983 --- [myapp
] [nio-8081-exec-3] o.s.s.w.a.logout.LogoutFilter            : Did not match request to Or [Ant [pattern='/logout', GET], Ant [pattern='/logout', POST], Ant [pattern='/logout', PUT], Ant [pattern='/logout', DELETE]]
2024-05-14T12:09:22.641+05:30 TRACE 29983 --- [myapp
] [nio-8081-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter (7/13)
2024-05-14T12:09:22.641+05:30 TRACE 29983 --- [myapp
] [nio-8081-exec-3] w.a.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter : Did not match request to Ant [pattern='/j_spring_security_check', POST]
2024-05-14T12:09:22.641+05:30 TRACE 29983 --- [myapp
] [nio-8081-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking RequestCacheAwareFilter (8/13)
2024-05-14T12:09:22.641+05:30 TRACE 29983 --- [myapp
] [nio-8081-exec-3] o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache        : matchingRequestParameterName is required for getMatchingRequest to lookup a value, but not provided
2024-05-14T12:09:22.641+05:30 TRACE 29983 --- [myapp
] [nio-8081-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter (9/13)
2024-05-14T12:09:22.641+05:30 TRACE 29983 --- [myapp
] [nio-8081-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking RememberMeAuthenticationFilter (10/13)
2024-05-14T12:09:22.641+05:30 TRACE 29983 --- [myapp
] [nio-8081-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking AnonymousAuthenticationFilter (11/13)
2024-05-14T12:09:22.642+05:30 TRACE 29983 --- [myapp
] [nio-8081-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking ExceptionTranslationFilter (12/13)
2024-05-14T12:09:22.642+05:30 TRACE 29983 --- [myapp
] [nio-8081-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking AuthorizationFilter (13/13)
2024-05-14T12:09:22.642+05:30 TRACE 29983 --- [myapp
] [nio-8081-exec-3] estMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager : Authorizing SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper[ org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter$HeaderWriterRequest@30582d24]
2024-05-14T12:09:22.642+05:30 TRACE 29983 --- [myapp
] [nio-8081-exec-3] estMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager : Checking authorization on SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper[ org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter$HeaderWriterRequest@30582d24] using org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizeHttpRequestsConfigurer$$Lambda$2203/0x000000700203a678@317e386b
2024-05-14T12:09:22.642+05:30 DEBUG 29983 --- [myapp
] [nio-8081-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured GET /login
2024-05-14T12:09:22.642+05:30 TRACE 29983 --- [myapp
] [nio-8081-exec-3] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to AnonymousAuthenticationToken [Principal=anonymousUser, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=b4f82d82-143b-43b7-98f6-27c4b78e141f], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ANONYMOUS]]
2024-05-14T12:09:22.642+05:30 DEBUG 29983 --- [myapp
] [nio-8081-exec-3] s.s.w.a.r.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter : SecurityContextHolder not populated with remember-me token, as it already contained: 'AnonymousAuthenticationToken [Principal=anonymousUser, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=b4f82d82-143b-43b7-98f6-27c4b78e141f], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ANONYMOUS]]'
2024-05-14T12:09:22.642+05:30 DEBUG 29983 --- [myapp
] [nio-8081-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/myapp
/login", parameters={}
2024-05-14T12:09:22.643+05:30 DEBUG 29983 --- [myapp
] [nio-8081-exec-3] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to com.r
.is
.controller.webapp.TokenAuthenticationController#loginPage(HttpServletRequest)
2024-05-14T12:09:22.658+05:30 DEBUG 29983 --- [myapp
] [nio-8081-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.view.JstlView            : View name 'login', model {isCaptchaEnabled=true}
2024-05-14T12:09:22.659+05:30 DEBUG 29983 --- [myapp
] [nio-8081-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.view.JstlView            : Forwarding to [/WEB-INF/views/login.jsp]
2024-05-14T12:09:22.660+05:30 TRACE 29983 --- [myapp
] [nio-8081-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=Ant [pattern='/api/**'], Filters=[]] (1/14)
2024-05-14T12:09:22.660+05:30 TRACE 29983 --- [myapp
] [nio-8081-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=Ant [pattern='/incorrectAttempt**'], Filters=[]] (2/14)
2024-05-14T12:09:22.660+05:30 TRACE 29983 --- [myapp
] [nio-8081-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=Ant [pattern='/acps'], Filters=[]] (3/14)
2024-05-14T12:09:22.660+05:30 TRACE 29983 --- [myapp
] [nio-8081-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=Ant [pattern='/verify/**'], Filters=[]] (4/14)
2024-05-14T12:09:22.660+05:30 TRACE 29983 --- [myapp
] [nio-8081-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=Ant [pattern='/token/**'], Filters=[]] (5/14)
2024-05-14T12:09:22.660+05:30 TRACE 29983 --- [myapp
] [nio-8081-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=Ant [pattern='/app/video/**'], Filters=[]] (6/14)
2024-05-14T12:09:22.660+05:30 TRACE 29983 --- [myapp
] [nio-8081-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=Ant [pattern='/auth/samlsso/**'], Filters=[]] (7/14)
2024-05-14T12:09:22.660+05:30 TRACE 29983 --- [myapp
] [nio-8081-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=Ant [pattern='/sso/provider/**'], Filters=[]] (8/14)
2024-05-14T12:09:22.660+05:30 TRACE 29983 --- [myapp
] [nio-8081-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=Ant [pattern='/tenant/company/auth/**'], Filters=[]] (9/14)
2024-05-14T12:09:22.660+05:30 TRACE 29983 --- [myapp
] [nio-8081-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=Ant [pattern='/signup/**'], Filters=[]] (10/14)
2024-05-14T12:09:22.660+05:30 TRACE 29983 --- [myapp
] [nio-8081-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=Ant [pattern='/mfaCode**'], Filters=[]] (11/14)
2024-05-14T12:09:22.660+05:30 TRACE 29983 --- [myapp
] [nio-8081-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=Ant [pattern='/countryMappingTemplate**'], Filters=[]] (12/14)
2024-05-14T12:09:22.660+05:30 TRACE 29983 --- [myapp
] [nio-8081-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=Ant [pattern='/WEB-INF/**'], Filters=[]] (13/14)
2024-05-14T12:09:22.660+05:30 TRACE 29983 --- [myapp
] [nio-8081-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : No security for GET /WEB-INF/views/login.jsp
2024-05-14T12:09:22.661+05:30 DEBUG 29983 --- [myapp
] [nio-8081-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 200 OK
2024-05-14T12:09:22.662+05:30 TRACE 29983 --- [myapp
] [nio-8081-exec-3] o.s.s.w.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter  : Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match request to [Is Secure]
2024-05-14T12:09:22.662+05:30 DEBUG 29983 --- [myapp
] [nio-8081-exec-3] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Did not store anonymous SecurityContext
2024-05-14T12:09:22.662+05:30 DEBUG 29983 --- [myapp
] [nio-8081-exec-3] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete request
 [nio-8081-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /login
2024-05-14T12:09:22.640+05:30 TRACE 29983 --- [myapp
] [nio-8081-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking DisableEncodeUrlFilter (1/13)
2024-05-14T12:09:22.641+05:30 TRACE 29983 --- [myapp
] [nio-8081-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter (2/13)
2024-05-14T12:09:22.641+05:30 TRACE 29983 --- [myapp
] [nio-8081-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking SecurityContextPersistenceFilter (3/13)
2024-05-14T12:09:22.641+05:30 TRACE 29983 --- [myapp
] [nio-8081-exec-3] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Did not find SecurityContext in HttpSession b4f82d82-143b-43b7-98f6-27c4b78e141f using the SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT session attribute
2024-05-14T12:09:22.641+05:30 TRACE 29983 --- [myapp
] [nio-8081-exec-3] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Created SecurityContextImpl [Null authentication]
2024-05-14T12:09:22.641+05:30 TRACE 29983 --- [myapp
] [nio-8081-exec-3] .s.s.w.c.SupplierDeferredSecurityContext : Created SecurityContextImpl [Null authentication]
2024-05-14T12:09:22.641+05:30 DEBUG 29983 --- [myapp
] [nio-8081-exec-3] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Set SecurityContextHolder to empty SecurityContext
2024-05-14T12:09:22.641+05:30 TRACE 29983 --- [myapp
] [nio-8081-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking HeaderWriterFilter (4/13)
2024-05-14T12:09:22.641+05:30 TRACE 29983 --- [myapp
] [nio-8081-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking CorsFilter (5/13)
2024-05-14T12:09:22.641+05:30 TRACE 29983 --- [myapp
] [nio-8081-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking LogoutFilter (6/13)
2024-05-14T12:09:22.641+05:30 TRACE 29983 --- [myapp
] [nio-8081-exec-3] o.s.s.w.a.logout.LogoutFilter            : Did not match request to Or [Ant [pattern='/logout', GET], Ant [pattern='/logout', POST], Ant [pattern='/logout', PUT], Ant [pattern='/logout', DELETE]]
2024-05-14T12:09:22.641+05:30 TRACE 29983 --- [myapp
] [nio-8081-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter (7/13)
2024-05-14T12:09:22.641+05:30 TRACE 29983 --- [myapp
] [nio-8081-exec-3] w.a.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter : Did not match request to Ant [pattern='/j_spring_security_check', POST]
2024-05-14T12:09:22.641+05:30 TRACE 29983 --- [myapp
] [nio-8081-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking RequestCacheAwareFilter (8/13)
2024-05-14T12:09:22.641+05:30 TRACE 29983 --- [myapp
] [nio-8081-exec-3] o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache        : matchingRequestParameterName is required for getMatchingRequest to lookup a value, but not provided
2024-05-14T12:09:22.641+05:30 TRACE 29983 --- [myapp
] [nio-8081-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter (9/13)
2024-05-14T12:09:22.641+05:30 TRACE 29983 --- [myapp
] [nio-8081-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking RememberMeAuthenticationFilter (10/13)
2024-05-14T12:09:22.641+05:30 TRACE 29983 --- [myapp
] [nio-8081-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking AnonymousAuthenticationFilter (11/13)
2024-05-14T12:09:22.642+05:30 TRACE 29983 --- [myapp
] [nio-8081-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking ExceptionTranslationFilter (12/13)
2024-05-14T12:09:22.642+05:30 TRACE 29983 --- [myapp
] [nio-8081-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking AuthorizationFilter (13/13)
2024-05-14T12:09:22.642+05:30 TRACE 29983 --- [myapp
] [nio-8081-exec-3] estMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager : Authorizing SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper[ org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter$HeaderWriterRequest@30582d24]
2024-05-14T12:09:22.642+05:30 TRACE 29983 --- [myapp
] [nio-8081-exec-3] estMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager : Checking authorization on SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper[ org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter$HeaderWriterRequest@30582d24] using org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizeHttpRequestsConfigurer$$Lambda$2203/0x000000700203a678@317e386b
2024-05-14T12:09:22.642+05:30 DEBUG 29983 --- [myapp
] [nio-8081-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured GET /login
2024-05-14T12:09:22.642+05:30 TRACE 29983 --- [myapp
] [nio-8081-exec-3] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to AnonymousAuthenticationToken [Principal=anonymousUser, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=b4f82d82-143b-43b7-98f6-27c4b78e141f], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ANONYMOUS]]
2024-05-14T12:09:22.642+05:30 DEBUG 29983 --- [myapp
] [nio-8081-exec-3] s.s.w.a.r.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter : SecurityContextHolder not populated with remember-me token, as it already contained: 'AnonymousAuthenticationToken [Principal=anonymousUser, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=b4f82d82-143b-43b7-98f6-27c4b78e141f], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ANONYMOUS]]'
2024-05-14T12:09:22.642+05:30 DEBUG 29983 --- [myapp
] [nio-8081-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/myapp
/login", parameters={}
2024-05-14T12:09:22.643+05:30 DEBUG 29983 --- [myapp
] [nio-8081-exec-3] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to com.r
.is
.controller.webapp.TokenAuthenticationController#loginPage(HttpServletRequest)
2024-05-14T12:09:22.658+05:30 DEBUG 29983 --- [myapp
] [nio-8081-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.view.JstlView            : View name 'login', model {isCaptchaEnabled=true}
2024-05-14T12:09:22.659+05:30 DEBUG 29983 --- [myapp
] [nio-8081-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.view.JstlView            : Forwarding to [/WEB-INF/views/login.jsp]
2024-05-14T12:09:22.660+05:30 TRACE 29983 --- [myapp
] [nio-8081-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=Ant [pattern='/api/**'], Filters=[]] (1/14)
2024-05-14T12:09:22.660+05:30 TRACE 29983 --- [myapp
] [nio-8081-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=Ant [pattern='/incorrectAttempt**'], Filters=[]] (2/14)
2024-05-14T12:09:22.660+05:30 TRACE 29983 --- [myapp
] [nio-8081-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=Ant [pattern='/acps'], Filters=[]] (3/14)
2024-05-14T12:09:22.660+05:30 TRACE 29983 --- [myapp
] [nio-8081-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=Ant [pattern='/verify/**'], Filters=[]] (4/14)
2024-05-14T12:09:22.660+05:30 TRACE 29983 --- [myapp
] [nio-8081-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=Ant [pattern='/token/**'], Filters=[]] (5/14)
2024-05-14T12:09:22.660+05:30 TRACE 29983 --- [myapp
] [nio-8081-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=Ant [pattern='/app/video/**'], Filters=[]] (6/14)
2024-05-14T12:09:22.660+05:30 TRACE 29983 --- [myapp
] [nio-8081-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=Ant [pattern='/auth/samlsso/**'], Filters=[]] (7/14)
2024-05-14T12:09:22.660+05:30 TRACE 29983 --- [myapp
] [nio-8081-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=Ant [pattern='/sso/provider/**'], Filters=[]] (8/14)
2024-05-14T12:09:22.660+05:30 TRACE 29983 --- [myapp
] [nio-8081-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=Ant [pattern='/tenant/company/auth/**'], Filters=[]] (9/14)
2024-05-14T12:09:22.660+05:30 TRACE 29983 --- [myapp
] [nio-8081-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=Ant [pattern='/signup/**'], Filters=[]] (10/14)
2024-05-14T12:09:22.660+05:30 TRACE 29983 --- [myapp
] [nio-8081-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=Ant [pattern='/mfaCode**'], Filters=[]] (11/14)
2024-05-14T12:09:22.660+05:30 TRACE 29983 --- [myapp
] [nio-8081-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=Ant [pattern='/countryMappingTemplate**'], Filters=[]] (12/14)
2024-05-14T12:09:22.660+05:30 TRACE 29983 --- [myapp
] [nio-8081-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=Ant [pattern='/WEB-INF/**'], Filters=[]] (13/14)
2024-05-14T12:09:22.660+05:30 TRACE 29983 --- [myapp
] [nio-8081-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : No security for GET /WEB-INF/views/login.jsp
2024-05-14T12:09:22.661+05:30 DEBUG 29983 --- [myapp
] [nio-8081-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 200 OK
2024-05-14T12:09:22.662+05:30 TRACE 29983 --- [myapp
] [nio-8081-exec-3] o.s.s.w.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter  : Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match request to [Is Secure]
2024-05-14T12:09:22.662+05:30 DEBUG 29983 --- [myapp
] [nio-8081-exec-3] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Did not store anonymous SecurityContext
2024-05-14T12:09:22.662+05:30 DEBUG 29983 --- [myapp
] [nio-8081-exec-3] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete request

Everything was working fine before migration to spring security 6

Checked the controller , for parameter(s) and duplicates (controller)  ?
Configure "$matchingRequestParameterName"  in spring sec config class

Flow is coming to my backend and returning model and view with view name. But still getting the issue.

View with that name exists in the specified path ?

yes view exist at specified path
